# Designing antenna to optimise return loss, which model might be a good start for a beginner?

Tags: machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, selection-operators

I am not very well versed with Machine learning. I am doing a small project as part of my coursework in my university. So I am trying to write a program tries to design a rectangular patch antenna using ML.

The input is the frequency of operation and output is the length, breadth, height and feed-point of the patch antenna. The length and breadth can be calculated with a formula. But for a good return loss, the height and feed-point position have to determined by some experimentation.

I am planning to use ML to predict these 2 values. My question is which ML model do you think will be good for implementing the above?
I have built a dataset which contains the length, breadth, height and feed-point of the patch antenna and the corresponding return loss.

Comment: Hi, welcome to AI stack exchange. It is good practice to write your qeustion briefly, but exactly as possible in the title, because it is the first thing people will see before deciding whether or not to look further or try to answer. I will make a short edit - if you disagree or want to re-word further that is fine, use the [edit] link for that.